# How do I find a set of certain classes and rename them?

Tags: java, refactoring, intellij-idea, rename

In my program I have a part which is called Sales Orders, it has GUIs, DAOs, property files and more and more.

I somehow want to find out all these classes and create new same functionality classes from them with a different name.

Actually it is like renaming all of them. I am using `IDEA IntelliJ`, but I can use some other IDEs also.

What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: Do you want do *rename* then or do you want to *copy* them to new files with different names?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can you just copy them into a new Java package instead of renaming the classes? Do you want to rename them in a consistent way (e.g. automatically add "_2" to the end of the name) or do you need to choose names for each of them (if so, do it using `refactor->rename` in the Eclipse IDE, though I expect there's an equivalent in IntelliJ)

Comment: @DNA you are right, if he wants to rename them he can use this method. But i don't understand why he wants this. xmux, if you want to somehow hide your original classes look for Java obfuscation techniques.

Comment: i know what you are asking. You have to copy a new file of each existing and use replace with `sales` with `order` in the code. However you might face issues when it comes to method names, if the naming is inconsistent. I did this sometime for an assignment. There was already one flow given and asked me to do it for another one!

Comment: actually i want to do copy them to new files with different names, and i want to have the same functions like the old one but in a new window . Actually a replica of this part of the software with different method names, classes and DB tables.
So actually only refactor->rename could work, but i dont know how it will effect all the places, the project is really big and it has everywhere pieces.. Like Core, Client, Server.

Comment: this smells like heavy code duplication, which should be avoided

Comment: actually yes! it will cause definitively heavy code duplication, i think it is a test for me and they wanna see how am i going to survive.. By the way in IntelliJ F5 copies the class and u can edit it directly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse, you can simply select the file(s), copy them and then paste (without selecting anything else).

Eclipse will then notice that the files already exist and offer you a dialog where you can enter new names.

Alternatively, you can copy the `.java` files using your desktop (Explorer on Windows). IDEA will notice after a refresh and show a couple of errors (because the names of the files don't match the class names). It should then offer you quick fixes to rename the new classes to match the file name.

Comment: this could be a nice one also, but i need to change the method names also.. i found out right now javaparser, i am going to try it first, then using IDE tools.

Comment: You can use the "Rename" refactoring to change method names after renaming the files.